# GDB freezes when shell spawns

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, gdb

I have a simple C program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    execve(argv[1], &argv[1], NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

If i run `gdb --tui myprogram` and spawn a shell with the command `run "/bin/sh"` then gdb will freeze, and i can only terminate it with CTRL-C.

My purpose is to execute shell commands from within gdb (I have a buffer overflow homework)

Is there a way to use the shell from within gdb?

### EDIT

I solved the problem removing the `--tui` option.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using gdbserver. This helpfully disassociates the gdb session from the binary. I use it to debug ncurses text UIs for instance.

On term1:

```
$ gdbserver :2345 /path/to/my/program
```

On term2:

```
$ gdb -q /path/to/my/program
> target remote localhost:2345
> break ......
> continue
```

When you run gdb in term2, do it from the directory where the source lives.

Also, once you know how to do this you can debug machines over the network. You can also debug from a x86 box a process running on a remote arm if you have the right tools in place. So this is another tool to add to the toolbox.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i solved the problem by simply removing the "-tui" option.